# how to creat mobile screen comparable web site?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I make my website mobile, because if my website is viewed on mobile device, then my website design doesn;t fit, the header& footer are unbalanced.

Please suggest what change in my web site good view on mobile.

Comment: [**Media Queries**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [mediaqueries](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-media-queries)*, you should do resarch on [responsive design](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/12/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/):

```
body{
    background-color: red;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    body{
        background-color: green;
    }

}
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    body{
        background-color: yellow;
    }
}
```

The code above is a simple example. The body will be red by default, green if the device is smaller than 800px and yellow when smaller than 500px. You can do this for print only, or `min-width:1024px`, or `orientation:landscape`. Plenty of options :)

**A tip**:
This tip will save you a lot of time: Instead if defining widths for different devices, use standard block behaviour. This will give you the option to use the element as 100% minus margin/padding/border.

```
#wrapper{
    width: auto;
    display: block;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

**In the link provided there are examples for iPhone only. I suggest you keep it as broad as you can, this will be better in the long run*

Comment: Just an FYI, it is a best practice to define the default CSS rules for the smallest screen and use the media queries to change the rules as the viewport expands. I say this based on experience. You are doing large down to small, which is what most devs do because they come from the large screen.